# Correcting for individual differences in the usage (employed range) of rating scales

Tags: repeated-measures, scales, psychometrics, rating

Experiments that collect subjective ratings (e.g. on a Likert 1-7 scale) necessarily have to account for between-subjects differences in how the range of the rating scale is used by different people, i.e. the fact that, for various reasons, some subjects are quite restrictive in their usage of the scale (e.g. they rarely rate lower than 3 or higher than 5), while others use up the entire scale quite liberally. I know that for this problem it suffices to simply z-score all the raw ratings within each subject.

However, another problem that often occurs with such data sets is when it turns out (as per post-study debriefings) that subjects change their scale-using strategy during the course of the experiment, such as for instance if they realise that an item they've previously rated 7 was in fact not really worthy of a 7 rating, since the current item is in fact "worthy of a 7", and so they wish they could go back and correct the previous rating to, say, a 5 or a 6 - which the experimental paradigm might not allow them to do.

My question: Is there any statistical way to correct for this second sort of problem, i.e. within-subject variability in the rating scale usage? Clearly, z-scoring the ratings within-subject does nothing to fix this sort of mid-experiment strategy change in how the scale ratings are given; and in fact only works to eliminate between-subjects variability if the within-subjects variability described above is assumed to be negligible.

Note that, to a previous [question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/13869/group-differences-reflecting-different-use-of-a-rating-scale-vs-actual-differenc) I had on the topic of rating scales, someone helpfully suggested that the problem of between-subject variability can be reduced by using "anchor points" during the instructions, i.e. providing examples to subjects of what a "1" stimulus, as well as what a "7" stimulus, are respectively like. This would of course solve both problems described above, but does assume that the right instructions were given during data collection, whereas my question concerns correction of an existing data set, one that presumably did not inocculate against this beforehand.

Comment: Would you have any way of knowing which items had been retrospectively overrated? Or by how much they had overrated them? If all your rating scales were measuring the same unidimensional latent variable, and you believed that items in the first half were no more difficult on average than those in the second half, then you could adjust the first half ratings to have the same mean as the second half but that seems _really_ crude.

Comment: If you believed that all your participants were doing this then I suppose you could perhaps fit a partial credit model, although that would carry a full set of assumptions that may or may not be the case.

Comment: Unfortunately the information I have about the retrospective correction (change in rating strategy) is very scarce and largely based upon (some) subject debriefings, so any  post-hoc correction of the rating data set seems inappropriate. I am rather thinking how to inocculate against this sort of thing for future experiments. Seems to me giving examples of *min* and *max* stimuli (i.e. anchoring) from the onset is the only (simple) workaround?...

Comment: Anchoring seems sensible in future. The other obvious solution is to change the paradigm to allow participants to change their responses, but that may not be practical depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you think there has been a widespread drift in responses during the study can you add a moderator variable for question number to take out any linear drift? Of course it may also take out a genuine change over time.

Comment: I doubt this was a linear phenomenon, that could be corrected with a moderator variable. For some subjects (not all), the item they currently had to rate (deserving of an extreme, i.e. min/max, rating) made them realise they had used such an extreme rating too generously earlier; as they cannot go back, they have no choice but give the same extreme rating, even though they would have rated the previous item more moderately in retrospect. I do not have the complete list of subjects for whom this occurred, and which was the stimulus that made some subjects have the "retrospective realisation".